# RHEL 8.2 podman rootless container network bottleneck at 20Mbits/s

Tags: python, rhel, podman

When I run container by podman 1.6.4 on RHEL8.2 (fresh install) with rootless user.
The maximum upload speed per container will be around 22Mbits/s (with 1Gbits/s network)
After start a second process, total network usage will go up to ~45Mbits/s (~ 23Mbits/s per container)
Then start a third process, total network usage will go up to ~74Mbits/s (~ 23Mbits/s per container)
So, I suspect that network speed limitation might be something from podman container.
Does anyone know how to disable upload speed limit for rootless container in RHEL?

====
Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8-slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir boto3

COPY . .
ENTRYPOINT ["python","upload.py"]
```

upload.py will upload a million of files with multithread to AWS S3.

After investigate, I found similar bug here
Rootless network serious bandwidth reduction? #8834
https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/8834
After change mtu to 1500 or 9000, upload speed still limit at ~23Mbits/s.
I also try to change net work to host with `--network=host` but the speed's not change.
So, it might not be related with these bug report.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a network for software development related questions. Issues word system administration can be asked in one of our sibling sites which can be found in the top menu.